# Creating patterns from SPIED

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

Is there any way to create only patterns from SPIED tool provided by Stanford? I wonder if I can extract patterns without running whole bunch of bootstrapping tool.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at allPatternsDir flag in the properties file. The format of the file depends on whether you are using memory or lucene to save your patterns.

If you don't want to run the bootstrapping tool, you can set learn=false.

For more, checkout the CreatePatterns class and the java classes to see what's the format of the file generated by allPatternsDir

Comment: Thanks it worked. Is there also a way to match created patterns to text (I need to extract new instances)? Should I utilize standard pattern matcher?